# How to append out and err stream print in log file using log4j through properties file

Tags: java, apache, logging, console, log4j

How to append System.out.println() and System.err.println() in log file by using log4j properties file in project.

```
    log=E:/log

    log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG,CONSOLE,FILE

    log4j.appender.CONSOLE=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
    log4j.appender.CONSOLE.File=${log}/log_out.txt
    log4j.appender.CONSOLE.Target=System.out
    log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
    log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout.conversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p - %m%n

    log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
    log4j.appender.FILE.File=${log}/log_err.txt
    log4j.appender.FILE.MaxFileSize=512KB
    log4j.appender.FILE.MaxBackupIndex=3
    log4j.appender.FILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
    log4j.appender.FILE.layout.conversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p - %m%n
```

I'm facing an error `log4j:WARN No such property [file] in org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender.`

Answer (score 1):

`log4j.appender.CONSOLE.File=${log}/log_out.txt` is not needed here, only `log4j.appender.FILE.File=${log}/log_err.txt` will do.

You are getting above error because `log4j.appender.CONSOLE=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender` represents this class needs to be used as an appender in log4j, which does not contain `file` field. `ConsoleAppender` is used to append the console and `RollingFileAppender` writes it to the file specified.